# How to use Assert.assertTrue in anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, junit

Im want to test a propertyChangeSupport. For that, I wrote this Test:

```
    private boolean changeRecognized = false;

    @Test
    public void testAddMapObject(){
        Bot testBot = new Bot(UUID.randomUUID(), "test", new GeoPoint(0d, 0d));
        PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName() == "mapObjekt")
                    changeRecognized = true;
            }
        };
        testListe.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        testListe.addMapObjekt(testBot);
        Assert.assertTrue(changeRecognized );
    }
```

Is there a way to move the `Assert.assertTrue` into the `PropertyChangeListener`? I tried it, but the test passed every Time, even when I didn't call `testListe.addMapObject(testBot)`

Comment: change this `evt.getPropertyName() == "mapObjekt"` before thinking about UT

Comment: @Eugene why? it's working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a named class for this:

```java
class SomeTest ...
    static class SpyListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        private boolean changeRecognized = false;

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getPropertyName() == "mapObjekt") {
                changeRecognized = true;
            }
        }

        public void assertRecognized() {
            Assert.assertTrue(changeRecognized);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddMapObject() {
        Bot testBot = new Bot(UUID.randomUUID(), "test", new GeoPoint(0d, 0d));
        SpyListener listener = new SpyListener();
        testListe.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        testListe.addMapObjekt(testBot);
        listener.assertRecognized();
    }
...
```